# Custom WM profile - issues with codec

Tags: c++, windows, directshow, encoder, windows-media-encoder

I create my custom WM encoder profile. The reason I need a custom, non 
standard WM profile is that I need that the video resolution must be 
the same as input video stream. I created below profile but after I 
encode my video and audio with it, the WMP while loading says that the 
WMV1 codec is not found and prompts me for downloading WM encoder 
codecs. After installing them, the problem still exists.

```
<profile version="589824" 
             storageformat="1" 
             name="mReplay Hi-End profile; WM Format 9; Audio &amp; 
Video" 
             description="Streams: 1 audio 1 video"> 
                   <streamconfig 
majortype="{73647561-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}" 
                   streamnumber="1" 
                   streamname="Audio Stream" 
                   inputname="Audio409" 
                   bitrate="320008" 
                   bufferwindow="-1" 
                   reliabletransport="0" 
                   decodercomplexity="" 
                   rfc1766langid="en-us" 
 > 
             <wmmediatype 
subtype="{00000161-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}" 
                   bfixedsizesamples="1" 
                   btemporalcompression="0" 
                   lsamplesize="14861"> 
           <waveformatex wFormatTag="353" 
                         nChannels="2" 
                         nSamplesPerSec="44100" 
                         nAvgBytesPerSec="40001" 
                         nBlockAlign="14861" 
                         wBitsPerSample="16" 
                         codecdata="008800000F0035E80000"/> 
            </wmmediatype> 
            </streamconfig> 
                   <streamconfig 
majortype="{73646976-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}" 
                   streamnumber="2" 
                   streamname="Video Stream" 
                   inputname="Video409" 
                   bitrate="100000" 
                   bufferwindow="-1" 
                   reliabletransport="0" 
                   decodercomplexity="AU" 
                   rfc1766langid="en-us" 
                           vbrenabled="1" 
                           vbrquality="95" 
                           bitratemax="0" 
                           bufferwindowmax="0"> 
                     <videomediaprops maxkeyframespacing="80000000" 
                                     quality="100"/> 
             <wmmediatype 
subtype="{31564D57-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}" 
                   bfixedsizesamples="0" 
                   btemporalcompression="1" 
                   lsamplesize="0"> 
       <videoinfoheader dwbitrate="100000" 
                        dwbiterrorrate="0" 
                        avgtimeperframe="400000"> 
        <rcsource left="0" 
                  top="0" 
                  right="0" 
                  bottom="0"/> 
        <rctarget left="0" 
                  top="0" 
                  right="0" 
                  bottom="0"/> 
            <bitmapinfoheader biwidth="0" 
                              biheight="0" 
                              biplanes="1" 
                              bibitcount="24" 
                              bicompression="WMV1" 
                              bisizeimage="0" 
                              bixpelspermeter="0" 
                              biypelspermeter="0" 
                              biclrused="0" 
                              biclrimportant="0"/> 
       </videoinfoheader> 
            </wmmediatype> 
            </streamconfig> 
     <streamprioritization> 
      <stream number="1" mandatory="0"/> 
      <stream number="2" mandatory="0"/> 
     </streamprioritization> 
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

That guid for your media subtype is incorrect:  31564D57-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71 is Windows Media 7 (aka WMV1).

Install [Windows Media Encoder 9](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5691ba02-e496-465a-bba9-b2f1182cdf24&displaylang=en).  It comes with a profile editor, so all you have to do is double click on the .prx file, or load it up and create a new profile.

Comment: Hello

I did that before. The same problem occurs when I create the profile in profile editor and save it as prx file. The issue is the profile is producing "incorrect video" only if the target resolution is set to 0,0,0,0 (meaning that the video resolution is not preconfigured but has to be the same as video input resolution). For some reason WME can't handle this. I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

the ability to handle 0,0,0,0 (or any other video size) depends on the encoding. WMV7 and WMV9 should support it though. Use WME9 to export a profile that has "same as input" checked in video options and compare it to your profile..